# doc.getPage and add it to new document gives blank pages in output pdf in PDFBox 3.0.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

In this the final pdf I am getting is having blank pages while using pdfbox 3.0.0 but while using same code with pdfbox 2.0.29 version it is perfectly working.

```
pdfDoc1 = new PDDocument();
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) { 
     PDPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i - 1);       
     pdfDoc1.addPage(page);
}

PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
boolean key = false;
if (acroForm != null) {
for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
     if (field instanceof PDSignatureField) {
    key = true;
    break;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: This can't work, your document is empty. I suspect this isn't your actusl code. And the current version is 3.0.1. However bugs exist related to import "foreign" documents in 3.0.*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.